# Change Text When Going to Previous Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a website where, upon choosing an item in the menu bar, the screen moves to a specific spot on the page. I then made a function in which the text changes in two spots, "titletext" and "infotext". Example:

```
<li><a href="#content" onclick='changeText()'>Weeee!</a></li>
```

It works but now I realize I have a problem: When I choose to go back to the previous page, the text remains the same, until the user chooses to refresh the page.

Using Javascript, how can I tell the website to change the text when (for example) the page is on `#content` and change the text again when it's on the home page? Do I have to take a different approach with my code?

Below is my code for changeText():

```
function changeText(){
    document.getElementById('titletext').innerHTML = 'Mission Statement';
    document.getElementById('infotext').innerHTML = 'RANDOMTEXT';
}
```

**EDIT**: Here's an example of what I want my website to do.

> When the user hits the back button on the browser, the text changes to
>   the previous text. So if it shows "Hey" then it shows "Bye", when the
>   user hits the browser's back button, the code changes to "Hey"

Comment: Please don't put psedotags like `[javascript]` into your question titles. That's what we have tags for.

Comment: Sorry. I will remember that next time. :)

Comment: Do you mean you want the text to change when you scroll back to a specific spot? Or just when you click another anchor?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question with some explicit example?

Comment: When the user hits the back button on the browser, the text changes to the previous text. So if it shows "Hey" then it shows "Bye", when the user hits the browser's back button, the code changes to "Hey".

Comment: so your problem is you want the page to refresh when you return on it by using the browser's back button?

Comment: Kinda. The text changes based on what you choose. If there were two different buttons and the text displayed a default string then two other different strings based on what buttons you click, when you go through the previous pages, the text will change based off the history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>Take a look at [this jQuery plugin](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange) which allows you to listen to `#hash` change events. Basically, once you installed that plugin,</del> you can have something like this:

```
window.onhashchange = function() { //when the hash changes (the '#' part)
    var loc = window.location + ""; //get the current location (from the address bar)
    var curHash = loc.substr(loc.lastIndexOf("#")); //get what's after the '#'
    if(curHash == "#home") { //if it's #home
        //change text to whatever you want
    }
    else if(curHash == "#nav") { //else if it's #nav
        //similarly, change text appropriately
    }
    else if(curHash == "#content") {
        //change text, too
    }
};
```

**Edit:** Actually, the `onhashchange` is [already supported in current versions](http://caniuse.com/hashchange) of modern browsers. Use the same code above, but nevermind about the plugin.

There might be a simpler way to do this; but I hope this helped!

Comment: I'm sorry, as I said, I'm a developer noob. Is there a difference between jQuery and Javascript?

Comment: jQuery is a framework for javascript. So you write javascript, with the help of the jQuery API. See http://www.jquery.com

Comment: @parioscreations jQuery is a JavaScript library. So it adds extra functionality. Once you include jQuery, you can include the above plugin as well. See [jQuery.com](http://jquery.com).

Comment: @parioscreations See edit. No need for jQuery, it turns out.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this code confuses me. Could you please explain. :)

Comment: @parioscreations See edited code with comments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need a different approach,  the problem here is that your function fires only when you click the link and javascript - or the web rather - does not maintain state without workarounds. So use a client side routing library such as SammyJs to handle browser history. You then bind your ChangeText function to the event of changing the address rather than the click of the link.

So the link click changes the address (clientside using sammyjs) and then respond to the event of changing the address and if you hit back or refresh, your application state remains presereved.